# C# Open Office Documents and Xps Files from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an application for viewing Word and Excel Files via Xps Viewer. I convert office files to xps files and show it in WPF XPS Document Viewer.

But here is a little problem; I don't want the users see the files, i delete the files after closing.

I am wondering is there any solution to convert xps in to memory stream and view it in Xps Viewer

**Edit:**

I don't want create any xps file on disk. The convert process must done inside to MemoryStream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following lines of code worked fine for me on a poc project and can give you a starting point.
For the document conversion part (word/excel -> xps) you could just print them via automation using XPS Document Writer.

```
System.IO.Stream docStream = ...any xps as stream;
Package package = Package.Open(docStream);

//Create URI for Xps Package
//Any Uri will actually be fine here. It acts as a place holder for the
//Uri of the package inside of the PackageStore
string inMemoryPackageName = string.Format("memorystream://{0}.xps", Guid.NewGuid());
Uri packageUri = new Uri(inMemoryPackageName);

//Add package to PackageStore
PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);

XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, inMemoryPackageName);
FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

// Do operations on xpsDoc here
DocViewer.Document = fixedDocumentSequence;

//Note: Please note that you must keep the Package object in PackageStore until you
//are completely done with it since certain operations on XpsDocument can trigger
//delayed resource loading from the package.

//PackageStore.RemovePackage(packageUri);
//xpsDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Here is another idea for the conversion part http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907.aspx

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate this line: System.IO.Stream docStream = ...any xps as stream; I really do not know what is that "any xps". Sorry

Answer (score 0):

please show some code...

If your XPS document is written into a stream you could pass that stream to `Package.Open` then the Package to `XpsDocument` then the `Xpsdocument` to `DocumentViewer`... this way the xps stays in memory all the time.

For example Aspose.Words/.Cells can generate XPS from word and Excel into a stream - so no files involved...

Comment: My XPS is out as file on disk.

Comment: then load it via FileStream OR use some 3rd-party libarary to generate XPS directly into memory stream (no files at all)... one such 3rd-party solution is Aspose... I am not affiliated, just a happy customer.

Comment: I dont want pay to components.